# Python - proportion of values of a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops

I have been trying to create a function that returns a dataframe out of a proportion of values from a given dataframe.

For example, from the set of customers who replied to a survey, 56% are Female and 44% are Male.

This is the fucntion I built:

```
def proportion_to_the_whole_dataset(dataset,dataset_column):
    proportion_dataset = pd.DataFrame(columns=[dataset_column.name,'%'])
    for i in range(dataset_column.value_counts().index.size):
        for element in dataset_column.value_counts().index:
            proportion_dataset = pd.DataFrame({dataset_column.name: element,'%': round((dataset[dataset_column == element].size/dataset.size)*100,2)},index=[i])
        return proportion_dataset
```

However the result I am getting is:

Gender    %

0 Male 44.0

Is there any issue sin the loops I am using?

Comment: What output do you expect? Exactly?

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting every time your variable `proportion_dataset`. You can append your result for each loop and concatenate it in return like this.

```
def proportion_to_the_whole_dataset(dataset,dataset_column):
    proportion_dataset = pd.DataFrame(columns=[dataset_column.name,'%'])
    temp = []
    for i in range(dataset_column.value_counts().index.size):
        for element in dataset_column.value_counts().index:
            temp.append(pd.DataFrame({dataset_column.name: element,'%': round((dataset[dataset_column == element].size/dataset.size)*100,2)},index=[i]))
        return pd.concat(temp)
```

As suggested, your approach is not leveraging the power of pandas. Therefore a better solution would be to simply:

```
def proportion(df, col):
    df = df[col].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
    df = df.to_frame()
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.columns = [col, '%']
    return df
```

where col is the column name you are analysing as a string

Comment: Looping like that in pandas frankly sounds like a total misuse of the library.

Comment: @MadPhysicist totally agree.. but he asked what was wrong in his loop, not a different approach.. so

Comment: @MadPhysicist better now?

Comment: @Caio Garcia, if this is what you were looking for, pls accept the answer